# What does this error means?

Tags: bash, gedit

When I put the input command ;

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

I got the text editing terminal screen added export PATH .... and other lines saved them. But in the command line terminal, I saw these :

```
(gedit:4035): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files.
```

What does this mean and what should I do ?

Comment: Can you sudo to the file? What happened finally, are you able to edit the file?

Comment: That's a warning.  It's not typically a critical software failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running a graphical program (`gedit`) with `sudo` which usually is for command line use. There is a problem defining a graphical environment for root in this case. It is preferably to use `gksudo` for running graphical programs.